# BaseAdapter not recognizing button onclick in listview

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have created a `ListView` in which there is a list of recordings which the user has recorded. It is working fine with one file, but when there are multiple recordings only the last recording plays every time the user clicks on any of the recordings. Also it is not showing the total and current time correctly.

**Here is My Java File**

```
    package com.example.idictate;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Unsent_ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    int flag = 0;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int i=0;
    int playCount=0,playTag=(-1);    
    MediaPlayer durationSetPlayer;
//  MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    TimerManager timerManager;
    File unsent_File;
    String unsent_root_sd;
    int buttonTagHold=-1;
    Runnable runCaller1,runCaller2;
    Handler mHandler1 = new Handler();
    Handler mHandler2 = new Handler();
       private int stateMediaPlayer;
        private final int stateMP_NotStarter = 0;
        private final int stateMP_Playing = 1;
        private final int stateMP_Pausing = 2;
//  private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; 
      List<String>  str;
    public Unsent_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String>           allUnsentFiles) {
        mContext=context;
        str=allUnsentFiles;
        timerManager = new TimerManager();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        unsent_root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();      
        durationSetPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
        }
     static class HoldingClass{
        static Button bpaly;
        TextView title;
        TextView curr_duration;
        TextView totl_duration;
        CheckBox listCheBox;

    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return str.size();
    }

       @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return str.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
//      View row=convertView;
        final HoldingClass holdingClass=new HoldingClass();
        holdingClass.title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_title_tv);
        holdingClass.curr_duration=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_curr_duration_tv);
        holdingClass.totl_duration=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_total_duration_tv);
        holdingClass.bpaly=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.list_play_btn);

        holdingClass.listCheBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.list_chbox);

    //  Log.v("********* : ",""+position);

        holdingClass.title.setTag(position);
        holdingClass.curr_duration.setTag(position);
        holdingClass.totl_duration.setTag(position);
        holdingClass.bpaly.setTag(position);
                holdingClass.listCheBox.setTag(position);

//      play Pause code
        holdingClass.bpaly.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                     switch (stateMediaPlayer) {
                    case stateMP_NotStarter:
                        durationSetPlayer.start();
               holdingClass.bpaly.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
                        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Playing;
                        break;
                    case stateMP_Playing:
                        durationSetPlayer.pause();
                        holdingClass.bpaly.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paly_button);
                        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Pausing;
                        break;
                    case stateMP_Pausing:
                        durationSetPlayer.start();
                        holdingClass.bpaly.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
                        stateMediaPlayer = stateMP_Playing;
                        break;
                    }
//                    if(!durationSetPlayer.isPlaying()){
//                    if(durationSetPlayer  != null){
//                          durationSetPlayer.start();
//////                          // Changing button image to play button
//                          holdingClass.bpaly.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paly_button);
//                      }
//                    }
//                      else if(durationSetPlayer.isPlaying()){
//                           if(durationSetPlayer  != null){
//                          durationSetPlayer.pause();
//////                          // Changing button image to pause button
//                          holdingClass.bpaly.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_button);
//                      }
//      }
//          



//              Log.v("*** "+holdingClass.paly.getTag(),holdingClass.listCheBox.getTag()+"  "+holdingClass.title.getTag());

                unsent_File = new File( unsent_root_sd + "/iDictate/unsnt/"+holdingClass.title.getText()+".wav") ; 

                try{
                    if(var.mPlayer_unsnt.isPlaying()){
                        mHandler1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        mHandler2.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        var.mPlayer_unsnt.stop();
                        updateView(buttonTagHold);
var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                        var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                        var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(true);
                    }
//                  var.mPlayer_unsnt.reset();

                    var.mPlayer_unsnt.setDataSource(unsent_File.toString());
                    var.mPlayer_unsnt.prepare();
                    var.mPlayer_unsnt.start();

                    buttonTagHold=(Integer)holdingClass.bpaly.getTag();
                        var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(false);
                    var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                    var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(false);

                }catch(Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               playerButton();


                var.mPlayer_unsnt.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        mHandler1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        mHandler2.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

                           if((Integer)holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag()==buttonTagHold)  {
                        holdingClass.curr_duration.setText("00:00:00");
                        }
                        buttonTagHold=-1;
//                      Log.v("*** ","complete track");
                          var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(true);
                        var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                        var.tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(true);

                    }
                });


            }
            public void playerButton(){


                final Runnable  runCaller1=new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if((Integer)holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag()==buttonTagHold) {

                            holdingClass.curr_duration.setText(timerManager.milisecondToTime(var.mPlayer_unsnt.getCurrentPosition()));
                            mHandler1.postDelayed(this, 100);                                               //her 1 minut k antral se chalege
                            Log.v("1***","runCaller : "+holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag());
                        }
                    }
                };
                mHandler1.postDelayed(runCaller1, 10);



            }

            private void updateView(int index){
                View v = var.unsent_ListView.getChildAt(index - 
                        var.unsent_ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_curr_duration_tv);
                someText.setText("00:00:00");

            }
        });


        holdingClass.listCheBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean arg1) {
                    int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
//              Log.v("***onChecked "+arg1,""+position);
                var.unsent_Checkboxs.set(position, arg1);
            }
        });

        holdingClass.listCheBox.setChecked(var.unsent_Checkboxs.get(position));
        holdingClass.title.setText(str.get(position));

        if(var.mPlayer_unsnt.isPlaying()){
        //  mHandler1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        //  mHandler2.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            if((Integer)holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag()==buttonTagHold){
                final Runnable runCaller2=new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
holdingClass.curr_duration.setText(timerManager.milisecondToTime(var.mPlayer_unsnt.getCurrentPosition()));
                        mHandler2.postDelayed(this, 100);                                               //her 1 minut k antral se chalege
                        Log.v("2***","runCaller : "+holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag());

                    }
                };
                mHandler2.postDelayed(runCaller2, 10);
            }
        }

//      if((Integer)holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag()==10)
//      {
//           runCaller=new Runnable() {
//                  
//                  public void run() {
//                          
//                      holdingClass.curr_duration.setText(timerManager.milisecondToTime(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
//                      handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);        //her 1 minut k antral se chalege
//                      Log.v("*** ","runCaller"+holdingClass.curr_duration.getTag());
//                  }
//              };
//              handler.postDelayed(runCaller, 10);
//      }
        try{

                durationSetPlayer.reset();
                durationSetPlayer.setDataSource(unsent_root_sd + "/iDictate/unsnt/"+holdingClass.title.getText()+".wav");
                durationSetPlayer.prepare();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         holdingClass.totl_duration.setText(timerManager.milisecondToTime(durationSetPlayer.getDuration()));

        return row;

    }
 }
```

**And XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center|left" >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/list_play_btn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/paly_button"
            android:focusable="false" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#787878" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/list_chbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:padding="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_curr_duration_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#787878" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_total_duration_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#787878" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the position in getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
```

If the position is incorrect, please use `final int position`